# Google Sheets API create then update in one script PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have successfully created functions to create a new Google Sheet with API v4. I have also created ones to append. Those are fine. I am now trying to combine the php code to first run the create function then the append function.

My current issue is after the sheet is created, during the append sheet part there is an ENTITY NOT FOUND error. Here is part of the error (I can post the entirety if you'd like.)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "errors": [ { "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ], "status": "NOT_FOUND" } }

at the end of the error I see append_to_sheet('1RrHFGzEuQ4zn_s...') which is displaying part of the correct sheetID that was created.
```

The beginning of each function (create and append) has the setting of the $client, $db, tokens and $service variables. Part of me thinks setting it twice may be causing the issue.

```
///call the functions
create_spreadsheet();  //creates sheet
append_to_sheet($var1);   //appends sheet using global variable


function create_spreadsheet() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
      $db = new DB();
      $arr_token = (array) $db->get_access_token();
    $accessToken = array(
        'access_token' => $arr_token['access_token'],
        'expires_in' => $arr_token['expires_in'],
    );
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);  
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
...other code...
         printf("Spreadsheet ID: %s\n", $spreadsheet->spreadsheetId);
//set global variable so other function can access it//
         global $var1;        
         $var1=sprintf("%s\n", $spreadsheet->spreadsheetId);
```

But I can call out the global $var1 in the append function and it will echo it correctly. To me that means it's part of that append function now.

```
function append_to_sheet($var1 = '') {
 global $var1;
echo "test carry-over: ".$var1;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $db = new DB();
    $arr_token = (array) $db->get_access_token();
    $accessToken = array(
        'access_token' => $arr_token['access_token'],
        'expires_in' => $arr_token['expires_in'],
    );
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
```

Comment: Is the spreadsheetID the same on both functions?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the post.

Comment: `$var1` is set to be `{$id}\n`. Have you tried to remove the line break?

Answer (score 0):

This was all my own fault. I was setting an extra character in the $var1. What an idiot. All fixed.